# How to save in my Application Settings the Checkbox' Checked in a Treeview?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, treeview, application-settings

I'm looking how to save the checked checkboxes in a treeview which contains a lot of folders and subfolders. Is it possible to save them in the application settings ?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but it doesn't sound like these are "application settings".  If you are saving a lot of folder and subfolder information, it might be better to save that information in your own XML file on the AppData folder.

Comment: @LarsTech
OK, but how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store a `Dictionary(Of String, Boolean)` and use the unique `Name` (or `FullPath`) property of each TreeNode:

```
    Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, Boolean)
    Dim stack As New Stack(Of TreeNode)

    For Each n As TreeNode In Me.TreeView1.Nodes
        stack.Push(n)
    Next

    While stack.Count > 0
        Dim node As TreeNode = stack.Pop()

        For Each subNode As TreeNode In node.Nodes
            stack.Push(subNode)
        Next

        d.Add(node.Name, node.Checked)
    End While

    ' Store d in My.Settings or somewhere else
```

To restore it is easy - loop over the dictionary and set the `Checked` values by name (or path).

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. However, i've got an error ArgumentException : An Element with the same key has been added. (excuse me for the translation, but i'm french and not sure of the translation i've done here. Error on this line : d.Add(node.Name, node.Checked)

Comment: @user1047402: Si vous changez `node.Name` à `node.FullPath` ça fonctionnera probablement.

Comment: merci, effectivement, ça marche maintenant. j'en profite pour vous demander si vous savez comment faire pour enregistre une bibliothèque dans les settings de mon application ? l'idée : je suis en train d'écrire un petit programme pour sauvegarder tous mes emails Outlook 2010 comme fichier .MSG ; Le problème étant d'arriver à sélectionner certains dossiers Outlook (ce que je fais à travers un treeview), et d'en ignorer certains autres. Je cherche une solution pour boucler parmi uniquement ces dossiers pour lancer mes sauvegardes. Thanks.